# WebSocketClientCompressionHandler id not found in netty4 jar

Tags: netty

i would like to use ready made compression handlers (specifically WebSocketClientCompressionHandler) located under

> io/netty/handler/codec/http/websocketx/extensions/compression/

however the entire folder wasnt found under netty-all-4.0.25.jar
is there a specific reason for it? 
what is the best way of using these examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only part of Netty 4.1, so you need to use 4.1.x for it.